# How can I handle different types of values for a select component?

Tags: reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, graphql

I am new to React, I am trying to do a select component, BUT the initial value coming from the API as a string so the selected value always empty because the values should be INT, and I can't change the labels to string since updating the gender should send an Int. any help what should I do here ?

```
const [gender, setGender] = useState(user.gender)
const genderOptions = [
  { id: 0, value: 0, label: 'Prefer Not To Answer' },
  { id: 1, value: 1, label: 'Female' },
  { id: 2, value: 2, label: 'Male' },
]

const handleChange = () => {
  setGender(parseInt(event.target.value,10))
}

return (
  <FormControl variant="outlined">
    <Styledelect
      id="genderId"
      name="gender"
      displayEmpty
      value={gender}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      {genderOptions.map((data) => (
         <StyledMenuItem key={data.id} value={data.value}>
           {data.label}
         </StyledMenuItem>
      ))}
    </Styledelect>
  </FormControl>
)
```

```
mutation updateEventWorker($eventWorkerId: ID!,$gender: Int) {
  updateEventWorker(eventWorkerId: $eventWorkerId, gender: $gender) {
    eventWorker {
      id
      user {
        gender
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
query eventWorkers {
  eventWorkers {
    user {
      gender
    }
  }
}
```

RESULT:

```
{ "data": {
   "eventWorkers": [{
     "user": {
       "gender": "female"
     }
   }]
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first look for the value then use it as initial state:

```
const genderOptions = [
    { id: 0, value: 0, label: 'Prefer Not To Answer' },
    { id: 1, value: 1, label: 'Female' },
    { id: 2, value: 2, label: 'Male' },
];
const initalState = genderOptions.find(opt => opt.label.toLowerCase() === user.gender.toLowerCase())?.value || null;

...

const [gender, setGender] = useState(initalState);
```